# Failed to execute goal org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.8:check (default) on project giraph-gora: Too many unapproved licenses: 56

Tags: eclipse, apache, maven, hadoop, giraph

I am new to Giraph and hadoop.I am trying to compile giraph using maven i tried using command `mvn -Phadoop_2 -fae -DskipTests clean install` on command prompt but i am getting error.[Image i attached is from eclipse(i am geting similar error in cmd as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHrBk.png).

```
GIRAPH version- 1.2.0 RC1
HADOOP version- 2.2.0
MAVEN version- 3.5.3
JAVA version 1.8.0_121
```

Any help in solving this problem will help me a lot. THANK YOU

Comment: Update the apache-rat-plugin to most recent version 0.12...

Comment: Where and how can i update rat version. I cannot find any rat jar file . thank you @ khmarbaise

Comment: Just update the version somewhere in your pom file there must be some entry about apache-rat-plugin or you are using a parent where it is defined?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you use a 1.2.0 RC1 instead of 1.2.0 ?

Comment: I am using a parent folder in eclipse to execute above command.And there is no reason for me to use 1.2.0 RC1(I just downloaded it from [link](https://github.com/apache/giraph/releases) )

Comment: add  param -Drat.numUnapprovedLicenses=200

Answer (score 6):

I found a **workaround** for this as I was facing a similar problem.

`mvn clean install -PallModules -Drat.numUnapprovedLicenses=200 -DskipTests`

> **`-Drat.numUnapprovedLicenses=200`** This helps to suppress the error.

Thanks @leftjoin for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a file created by Apache Rat in the path `giraph-gora/target/rat.txt` (as this is the failed project). This file will contain details on the files in your projects that do not have a proper licence (as well as the ones that do but these are not of any interest to you).

Most likely, the case is that the files produced by eclipse (.classpath, .project, org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs, org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs,org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs) are creating the problem. If you remove them you will be able to compile giraph properly.